# Spring cloud gateway: How to create a filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm new to spring cloud gateway.

I've been watching some of the youtube videos from the SpringDeveloper channel and am working on the following example:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {

    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/get")
            .addRequestHeader("X-SpringOne", "Awesome")
            .uri("http://httpbin.org:80"))
            .build();
}
```

Prior to looking at spring cloud gateway, i've also looked at Spring Netflix Zuul. I understand that in Netflix Zuul, you can create filters by creating a class that extends `ZuulFilter` and define it as a `pre`, `post`, `route`, etc.

However I was wondering how one can create a PRE/ POST filter using Spring cloud gateway?

Any help/ advice is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can give a look to : https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-zuul-filters/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/samplezuulfilters

Comment: that is for zuul not gateway

Answer (score 7):

For a pre filter here is [`AddRequestHeader`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/AddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.java) (code is executed before `chain.filter()` call):

```
public class AddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractNameValueGatewayFilterFactory {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(NameValueConfig config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                    .header(config.getName(), config.getValue())
                    .build();

            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        };
    }

}
```

For a 'post' filter, here is [`SetStatus`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/SetStatusGatewayFilterFactory.java) (code is run in lambda in `chain.filter(exchange).then()`):

```
public class SetStatusGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<SetStatusGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        final HttpStatus status = ServerWebExchangeUtils.parse(config.status);
        return (exchange, chain) -> {

            return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                // check not really needed, since it is guarded in setStatusCode,
                // but it's a good example
                if (!exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()) {
                    setResponseStatus(exchange, status);
                }
            }));
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: @spencergibb How is the filter added to the configuration or the route locator? If I add it via the Bean annotation to the application config its never been triggered.

Comment: Did anyone solved this? I couldn't found how to 'register' a custom filter to a route with RouteLocatorBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example in Kotlin: the URI `http://.../customers` is mapped to the URI obtained from the discovery service (*lb* = *load balanced*) for the service named `customer` and appended with "/". Furthermore, the forwarded request is enhanced with an additional header entry. Hope this helps.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
    @Bean
    fun routes(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder) = builder.routes {
        route {
            path("/customers")
            filters {
                setPath("/")
                addRequestHeader("aKey", "aValue")
            }
            uri("lb://customer")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he's looking for how to create a custom filter

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is the correct way to do it because I am also trying to achieve this behavior, I am thinking if this is something that needs to be done:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class CustomFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        //code for PRE filter

        Mono<Void> v = chain.filter(exchange);

        //code for POST filter
        return v;
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you or if you found another solution.